# Parse webpage table to List using Linq

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code that works fine:

```
        IList<IWebElement> allElement = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"users_table\"]"));
        foreach (IWebElement element in allElement)
        {
            string cellText = element.Text;
            Console.WriteLine(cellText);
        }
```

How to write values to List instead of Console? I have found an example, but in my case I don't have `td` elements. What is correct way of doing this?

```
        var HTMLTable = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"users_table\"]"))
          .FindElements(By.TagName("td"))
          .Select(e => e.Text)
          .ToList();
```

---

**EDIT:**

I have tried:

```
    var HTMLTable = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"users_table\"]"))
      .Select(e => e.Text)
      .ToList();
```

Comment: `driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"users_table\"]")).Select(e => e.Text).ToList()` ?

Comment: @GuruStron How come this is different what I have tried already? This oneliner does not give any errors and my attempt does not compile

Comment: You have `FindElement` instead of `FindElements` in the edit snippet.

Comment: will add as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as that:

```
var result = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"users_table\"]"))
    .Select(e => e.Text)
    .ToList();
```

In your snippet in edit part you have `FindElement`, which should return single element instead of collection, as `FindElements` does.